# How to use isset and operators as one ternary statement

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Is there a way of doing a ternary statement within a ternary statement. For example

```
@if (isset($checking))
<input type="radio" id="box" name="form" value="10"
{{$checking->myvalue == 10.0 ? 'checked' : ''}}/>
<label class="sister" for="boxwindow" title="myvalue_10" </label>
@else
<input type="radio" id="box" name="form" value="10"/>
<label class="sister" for="boxwindow" title="myvalue_10" </label>
@endif
```

however I would prefer it to look like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="box" name="form" value="10"
isset($checking->myvalue) == 10.0 ? 'checked' : ''}}/>
<label class="sister for="boxwindow" title="myvalue_10" </label>
```

This is so that I dont have to repeat the code within the else statement. Is this possible?

Just so you know my aim is to check the radio button but only if the dynamic number `isset` AND matches the given value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
{{ isset($checking->myvalue) && $checking->myvalue == 10 ? 'checked' : '' }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$foo = 1;
$bar = ($foo == 1) ? "1" : (($foo == 2)  ? "2" : "other");
echo $bar;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(isset($checking->myvalue) && $checking->myvalue == 10)?'checked' : '';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php echo isset($formData['employer_name'])?$formData['employer_name']:'_________________'; ?>
```